# React calls methods in hooks before declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have always been wondering how it works: we can call function expression in useEffect when it was defined below:

```
const Component = () => {
  useEffect(()=>{func()}, [])
  const func = () => console.log("Why?")
  return <></>
}
```

Will be glad for explanation or link to resource

Comment: The point is that react *doesn't* run the effect (call the `useEffect` callback) before `func` is  defined, it's called *after* the function component returned.

Comment: Do you know how closures work and what hoisting is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing specific to useEffect. In javascript in general, it's fine to create a function which references a function on a later line. Only when you *call* the function does it becomes a problem if you havn't finished initializing the variables.

```js
let a = () => {
  console.log('in a')
  b();
};

let b = () => {
  console.log('in b');
};

a(); // This is fine, both a and b have been initialized
```

```js
let a = () => {
  console.log('in a')
  b();
};

a(); // ERROR, because b has not been initialized

let b = () => {
  console.log('in b');
};
```

useEffect won't call your effect function until after the component has finished rendering, so well after `func` was defined.